# Creating an Object from getting tables in Sqlite3 database C++

Tags: c++, database, dictionary, sqlite

I am working on a project that gets the data from a sqlite3 database I had created to instantiate an object corresponding to each record in respect to the tables(table1, table2, table3).

Let's say, table1 is artist which has records of id and name. I had already populated the artist table using a text file, now I need to create an object and initialized accordingly. I am also supposed to implement a map to enumerate each object of "artist" class.

I am having trouble where to even start how to retrieve the records in the table so that I may map them accordingly.

Our professor gave us a sample code how to loop through the artist table but I'm not sure how to loop and map the data

```
  // loop each record in artist table
   sqlite3_stmt* statement;
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM artist", -1, &statement, NULL);
   while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {                 // get a record   
     printf(" artist id=%u ", sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0));      // its first field
     printf(" artist name=%s \n", sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)); // its second field
   }
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the loop iterating the table, just make a map (by using it from the C++ standard library) to store the table data:

```
 map<int, string> artists;
 sqlite3_stmt* statement;
 sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM artist", -1, &statement, NULL);
 while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
 {
     artists[sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)] = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1));
 }
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```